# Are there performance benchmarks of NumPy arrays in an IPython Notebook versus a .py script file?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with huge multidimensional NumPy arrays in an IPython notebook with Python3 and things are slow going.

Is it appreciably quicker to convert the `.ipynb` file into a `.py` file and run via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I have never noticed any performance penalty (5-6 million x 8 arrays here) with IPython/Jupyter, but even if there is some small difference it is unlikely to be noticeable. A much greater speed increase with a similarly low effort would come from writing performance sensitive code in cython, adding type annotations in cython would yield even greater increases. In my own work I have observed speedups of orders of magnitude from using cython smartly.